# Remove/skip few objects from ActiveRecord_Relation collection in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If you use select!,reject!,delete_if on AR collection

`@projects = Project.all` (has 3 records with status column value 'failed')

```
@projects.reject!{|p| p.status=="failed"} (has 0 records now)
```

But `@projects.count` => giving the result as 3 still

Means If we try to do any querying on @projects which is still using old collection(3 records).

Any suggestions? why its using old collection since have already filtered it by reject operation. and don't want it to use old AR collection.

Using AR `where`, we can achieve it but in my case, using `where` only could not achieve my result and need to some operation over the AR collection and it should return AR only not Array.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better of using the [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where):

```
@project.where.not(status: :failed)
```

`@projects.class` would return you a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which does not implement `reject!` method, thus you can't "modify" it as you try. And it won't make sense to be able to do so anyway.

## EDIT: (since the OP was edited)

I am sure your thing could be achieved by using query interface, but since you can not provide the concrete example, here's a non-efficient way, but why would you care about efficiency, right?

```
project_ids = @projects.reject { |p| p.status == "failed" }.map(&:id)
new_at_collection = Product.where(id: project_ids)
```

Comment: yes, agree. But could not achieve my expected result through only `where` and need to do operation over the AR collection it should return the AR collection but not array.

Comment: @Rajuakula you asked - I answered. Ask a new question showing specific issue, so that you can get specific answer.

Comment: @Rajuakula also, I noticed you never accept the answers to your questions - I suggest you start accepting the correct answers if they work for you - this way you let the community know that your problem is solved.

Comment: its not solve my problem. `@projects.reject!{|p| p.status='failed'}` also will return the class as `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Of course definitely will accept the right answer if its solve my problem. thanks